# django redistributable app with south

Tags: django, django-south

Django apps that are meant to be redistributed don't have a manage.py (nor a settings.py since that is part of the project, not the app).

How does one run schemamigration --auto in this scenario?  Do I need to have a minimal settings/manage.py as part of the app repository in order to do this?  Is there a way to do this with django-admin.py?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the app to your `Installed_Apps` in your `settings.py`

Then you can run `./manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --auto`

If the app doesn't have any migrations you will want to run `./manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --initial` first and then `./manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --auto` from then on.

Comment: The app doesn't have a settings.py or manage.py (that's the issue).  Apps are usually just the package with urls.py, models.py etc. withouth the project pieces (manage.py, settings.py)

Comment: Apps are just a set of views, models, and templates that can be added to a project. Projects are a collection of settings for an instance of Django and where the manage.py file resides. You need to add the app to an existing project or create one for it. See this SO answer for a description of the difference between an app and a project: http://stackoverflow.com/a/734321/992040

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But the models in redistributable apps can themselves have south migrations.  I can't at the moment find an example of a pluggable app that has model migrations.  Ideally, the app repository won't have project artifacts in it.

Comment: Yes, so when you add the pluggable app to your `Installed_Apps` in the project's `settings.py` and use the project's `manage.py` to run the schemamigration it will apply all the migrations in the pluggable app to the database defined in your project's settings.py

Comment: That's the way I'm working now (unfortunately).  This produces a migration py file in my virtualenv that then needs to be copied back to the app repository.  This feels like a very unsatisfactory solution since it would be nice to be able to run the schemamigration command without a specific context (since it's not actually needed to produce a migration for the app)

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to get this working in one of my project. Here's the code that works for me:

```
import sys

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command


if not settings.configured:
    settings.configure(
        ROOT_URLCONF='',
        DEBUG=False,
        DATABASES={
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': 'test.db'
            }
        },
        INSTALLED_APPS=(
            'south',
            'my_app',
        )
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_command('schemamigration', 'my_app', 
                 initial=len(sys.argv) > 1,
                 auto=len(sys.argv) == 0
```

The above script is saved as `migrate.py` and run with `python migrate.py` or `python migrate.py i` (the `i` can be anything, and it will use `--initial` instead of `--auto` if present). Obviously, you can do fancier command line option parsin, but this works for me.

EDIT: Updated the script, `DATABASES` key was missing. On this project, I used the same database for testing the code, so it's not an entirely arbitrary configuration.