# Adding a second project to a Django project

Tags: python, django, eclipse, import, project

I'm new to Django. I'm using Django with Eclipse. I've created a Django project using Eclipse (called "Django_Test_Project"). I've also created a PyDev project outside of Eclipse, using the command line (called "polls"). It has models.py, views.py, and tests.py.

I created "polls" using the following command:

```
    manage.py startapp polls
```

I want use Eclipse to add "polls" as a second project to "Django_Test_Project". How do I do that with a project that was created outside of Eclipse? Eclipse doesn't recognize "polls" as a project, probably because the project files are missing in "polls".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pls add folder & files listings for Django_Test_Project

Answer (score 4):

You are working on the Django tutorial, right? First of all, your terminology is not correct. You confuse a *project* with an *application* or *app* for short. It's no surprise that Eclipse doesn't recognize *polls* as a project, because it's not a project but an app.

In Django 1.4.1, the standard structure for a project called *mysite* is this:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Your *polls* app should go in the same directory where the file `manage.py` is located:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

You can just move the `polls` directory into the `mysite` directory using the Windows Explorer, Finder, Terminal etc. (depends on which OS you are running on). After refreshing the project view in Eclipse, your *polls* app should show up. In any case, you should read the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) more carefully as it basically answers your question already.

Additionally, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734255/what-is-the-difference-between-a-site-and-an-app-in-django) that explains the difference between projects and apps in a bit more detail.